# pyrocms installation in a subdirectory with wordpress installed in the root directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, pyro

Been at this for a while, so I figured I'd ask for help. Here's the .htaccess file for wordpress in the root:

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php5 .php
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php4

# BEGIN WordPress


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(community)(/|$)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm basically asking it to ignore the "community" directory, where pyrocms will be installed. Here's my .htaccess file in the community subdir:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 Options +FollowSymLinks
 RewriteEngine on

 # NOTICE: If you get a 404 play with combinations of the following commented out lines
 #AllowOverride All
 RewriteBase /community

 # Restrict your site to only one domain
 #RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
 #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L]

 # Keep people out of codeigniter directory and Git/Mercurial data
 RedirectMatch 403 ^/(system\/pyrocms\/cache|system\/codeigniter|\.git|\.hg).*$

 # Send request via index.php (again, not if its a real file or folder)
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

 <IfModule mod_php5.c>
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

 <IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

I get a 404 (the CI 404) when I try to access /community/installer

Additionally, if i try different settings for uri_proticol, I get weird results. db connection errors, etc. I've been able to get the main page of the installer to show, but no steps past that.

Any thoughts? Haven't found any docs for properly configuring pyrocms for a subdirectory installation.

Answer (score 0):

Restore your WordPress .htaccess (delete it, and regenerate it from the permalinks option in the panel).

Now, change your /community/.htaccess to this,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /community
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

What the hell are you doing that for?!

I may have made PyroCMS but I refuse to support something as mental as that ;-)

Comment: Yeah i know it. I actually figured out that the issue wasn't .htaccess related at all. Seemed to be related to this client being on godaddy shared hosting.